# jQuery syntax issues with .keyup()/.click() functions

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

New to stackover (and web development) so forgive me if I am making newbie mistakes. I am putting together a to-do list web app (http://jameswmoody.github.io/ShoppingList/) and I have a small bug that makes it so I have to click "Add" before I can use the Enter key the same way. I KNOW WHY THIS IS HAPPENING. I realize that my code as it exists requires that #add be clicked before it will listen out for the Enter key to be released. Problem is when I try to reformat the syntax, nothing I try works. Any suggestions? Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#add").click(function(){
    var text = $("#listInput").val();
    var item = $('<div class="list-item"><span></span></div>').text(text);

    item.on('dblclick', function(){
        $(this).fadeOut('fast');
    });
    item.on('click', function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('strike'); 
    });



$('#listInput').keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#add').click();
        };
    }); 

    if (text!=""){
        $("#listArea").append(item);
        $("#listInput").val("");
    }

    });

$(function(){

$('#listArea').sortable({ axis: "y" });
$('.list-item').draggable();
```

})
});

Comment: You have a space after click.

Comment: will you be able to create a demo using the [Code snippet Editor](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/prLqrfuh/1/)